# Block bootstrap from subject list

Tags: r, regression, plyr, statistics-bootstrap

I'm trying to efficiently implement a block bootstrap technique to get the distribution of regression coefficients.  The main outline is as follows.

I have a panel data set, and say firm and year are the indices.  For each iteration of the bootstrap, I wish to sample n subjects with replacement.  From this sample, I need to construct a new data frame that is an `rbind()` stack of all the observations for each sampled subject, run the regression, and pull out the coefficients. Repeat for a bunch of iterations, say 100.

- Each firm can potentially be selected multiple times, so I need to include it data multiple times in each iteration's data set.
- Using a loop and subset approach, like below, seems computationally burdensome.
- Note that for my real data frame, n, and the number iterations is much larger than the example below.

My thoughts initially are to break the existing data frame into a list by subject using the `split()` command.  From there, use

```
sample(unique(df1$subject),n,replace=TRUE)
```

to get the new list, then perhaps implement `quickdf` from the `plyr` package to construct a new data frame.

Example slow code:

```
require(plm)
data("Grunfeld", package="plm")

firms = unique(Grunfeld$firm)
n = 10
iterations = 100
mybootresults=list()

for(j in 1:iterations){

  v = sample(length(firms),n,replace=TRUE)
  newdata = NULL

  for(i in 1:n){
    newdata = rbind(newdata,subset(Grunfeld, firm == v[i]))
  }

  reg1 = lm(value ~ inv + capital, data = newdata)
  mybootresults[[j]] = coefficients(reg1)

}

mybootresults = as.data.frame(t(matrix(unlist(mybootresults),ncol=iterations)))
names(mybootresults) = names(reg1$coefficients)
mybootresults

  (Intercept)      inv    capital
1    373.8591 6.981309 -0.9801547
2    370.6743 6.633642 -1.4526338
3    528.8436 6.960226 -1.1597901
4    331.6979 6.239426 -1.0349230
5    507.7339 8.924227 -2.8661479
...
...
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `boot` package?

Comment: Yes, I have looked at and used the `boot` package.  I don't think it has the ability to do this type of block bootstrap, however.

Comment: It's a bit of a fudge and probably overkill using `boot`, but I think the answer I posted does the job.

Comment: Note also that `boot` allows you to easily run regressions on multiple cores, which can provide significant speed improvements for large numbers of replicates.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
myfit <- function(x, i) {
   mydata <- do.call("rbind", lapply(i, function(n) subset(Grunfeld, firm==x[n])))
   coefficients(lm(value ~ inv + capital, data = mydata))
}

firms <- unique(Grunfeld$firm)

b0 <- boot(firms, myfit, 999)
```

Comment: This appears to do exactly what I want -- thanks and extra credit for utilizing the `boot` package.  I have not used `do.call` before so this is helpful for that reason as well.  Cheers-

Comment: Do you know offhand how to deal with fixed effects (i.e. `factor(region)`) within `lm()` in the `boot` paradigm.  Since some factors might not show up in each iteration, the number of coefficients differs and it errors out.  Thoughts?

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful. Did you sort out the fixed-effects issue, by any chance? For this same reason, I'm having trouble comparing my target statistic across repetitions. My current strategy is to omit all FE coefficients in the vector I return in the 'myfit' function, but that seems a bit amateurish..

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the [tsboot](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/boot/html/tsboot.html) function in the `boot` package with fixed block resampling scheme.

```
require(plm)
require(boot)
data(Grunfeld)

### each firm is of length 20
table(Grunfeld$firm)
##  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
## 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20


blockboot <- function(data) 
{
 coefficients(lm(value ~ inv + capital, data = data))

}

### fixed length (every 20 obs, so for each different firm) block bootstrap
set.seed(321)
boot.1 <- tsboot(Grunfeld, blockboot, R = 99, l = 20, sim = "fixed")

boot.1    
## Bootstrap Statistics :
##      original     bias    std. error
## t1* 410.81557 -25.785972    174.3766
## t2*   5.75981   0.451810      2.0261
## t3*  -0.61527   0.065322      0.6330

dim(boot.1$t)
## [1] 99  3

head(boot.1$t)
##        [,1]   [,2]      [,3]
## [1,] 522.11 7.2342 -1.453204
## [2,] 626.88 4.6283  0.031324
## [3,] 479.74 3.2531  0.637298
## [4,] 557.79 4.5284  0.161462
## [5,] 568.72 5.4613 -0.875126
## [6,] 379.04 7.0707 -1.092860
```

Comment: `l=20` in your `tsboot()` statement will inevitably take a block with say 15 observations of one firm and 5 observations of another (=20), which is not what I want to do.  I either want to include all a firm's observations, or none, sometimes including the same firm's observations multiple times.

Comment: @baha-kev No...because the first step of the algorithm is to split the dataset (of 200 rows) in 10 block of 20 rows  (y_1, y_2, ..., y_10)  and the resample the dataset by block e.g (y_1, y_10, y_3, ...., y_1), (y2, y_9, ..., y3) and so on. And because of the organisation of the Grunfeld dataset each y_* correspond to one firm (every 20 rows). For more info look at [Bootstrap method and their Application](http://www.amazon.com/Bootstrap-Application-Statistical-Probabilistic-Mathematics/dp/0521574714) (page 396).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a method that should typically be faster than the accepted answer, returns the same results and does not rely on additional packages (except `boot`). The key here is to use `which` and integer indexing to construct each data.frame replicate rather than `split/subset` and `do.call/rbind`.

```
# get function for boot
myIndex <- function(x, i) {
  # select the observations to subset. Likely repeated observations
  blockObs <- unlist(lapply(i, function(n) which(x[n] == Grunfeld$firm)))
  # run regression for given replicate, return estimated coefficients
  coefficients(lm(value~ inv + capital, data=Grunfeld[blockObs,]))
}
```

now, bootstrap

```
# get result
library(boot)
set.seed(1234)
b1 <- boot(firms, myIndex, 200)
```

Run the accepted answer

```
set.seed(1234)
b0 <- boot(firms, myfit, 200)
```

Let's eyeball a comparison

using indexing

```
b1

ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot(data = firms, statistic = myIndex, R = 200)


Bootstrap Statistics :
       original      bias    std. error
t1* 410.8155650 -6.64885086 197.3147581
t2*   5.7598070  0.37922066   2.4966872
t3*  -0.6152727 -0.04468225   0.8351341
```

Original version

```
b0

ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot(data = firms, statistic = myfit, R = 200)


Bootstrap Statistics :
       original      bias    std. error
t1* 410.8155650 -6.64885086 197.3147581
t2*   5.7598070  0.37922066   2.4966872
t3*  -0.6152727 -0.04468225   0.8351341
```

These look pretty close. Now, a bit more checking

```
identical(b0$t, b1$t)
[1] TRUE
```

and

```
identical(summary(b0), summary(b1))
[1] TRUE
```

Finally, we'll do a quick benchmark

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(index={b1 <- boot(firms, myIndex, 200)}, 
              rbind={b0 <- boot(firms, myfit, 200)})
```

On my computer, this returns

```
Unit: milliseconds
  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 index 292.5770 296.3426 303.5444 298.4836 301.1119 395.1866   100
 rbind 712.1616 720.0428 729.6644 724.0777 731.0697 833.5759   100
```

So, direct indexing is more than 2 times faster at every level of the distribution.

*note on missing fixed effects*
As with most of the answers, the issue of missing "fixed effects" may emerge. Commonly, fixed effects are used as controls and the researcher is interested in one or a couple of variables that will be included with every selected observation. In this dominant case, there is no (or very little) harm in restricting the returned result of the `myIndex` or `myfit` function to only include the variables of interest in the returned vector.

Answer (score 2):

The solution needs to be modified to manage fixed effects.

```
library(boot)  # for boot
library(plm)   # for Grunfeld
library(dplyr) # for left_join

## Get the Grunfeld firm data (10 firms, each for 20 years, 1935-1954)
data("Grunfeld", package="plm")

## Create dataframe with unique firm identifier (one line per firm)
firms <- data.frame(firm=unique(Grunfeld$firm),junk=1)

## for boot(), X is the firms dataframe; i index the sampled firms
myfit <- function(X, i) {
    ## join the sampled firms to their firm-year data
    mydata <- left_join(X[i,], Grunfeld, by="firm")
    ## Distinguish between multiple resamples of the same firm
    ## Otherwise they have the same id in the fixed effects regression
    ## And trouble ensues
    mydata  <- mutate(group_by(mydata,firm,year),
                      firm_uniq4boot = paste(firm,"+",row_number())
                      )
    ## Run regression with and without firm fixed effects
    c(coefficients(lm(value ~ inv + capital, data = mydata)),
    coefficients(lm(value ~ inv + capital + factor(firm_uniq4boot), data = mydata)))
    }

set.seed(1)
system.time(b <- boot(firms, myfit, 1000))

summary(b)

summary(lm(value ~ inv + capital, data=Grunfeld))
summary(lm(value ~ inv + capital + factor(firm), data=Grunfeld))
```

Comment: Note that `uniq4boot` is a unique value for each firm+i, and this example includes a separate intercept for each uniq4boot, but has a single slope coefficient across all uniq4boot.

Answer (score 1):

I found a method using `dplyr::left_join` that is a bit more concise, only takes about 60% as long, and gives the same results as in the answer by Sean.  Here's a complete self-contained example.

```
library(boot)  # for boot
library(plm)   # for Grunfeld
library(dplyr) # for left_join

# First get the data
data("Grunfeld", package="plm")

firms <- unique(Grunfeld$firm)

myfit1 <- function(x, i) {
  # x is the vector of firms
  # i are the indexes into x
  mydata <- do.call("rbind", lapply(i, function(n) subset(Grunfeld, firm==x[n])))
  coefficients(lm(value ~ inv + capital, data = mydata))
}

myfit2 <- function(x, i) {
  # x is the vector of firms
  # i are the indexes into x
  mydata <- left_join(data.frame(firm=x[i]), Grunfeld, by="firm")
  coefficients(lm(value ~ inv + capital, data = mydata))
}

# rbind method
set.seed(1)
system.time(b1 <- boot(firms, myfit1, 5000))
  ##  user  system elapsed 
  ## 13.51    0.01   13.62 

# left_join method
set.seed(1)
system.time(b2 <- boot(firms, myfit2, 5000))
   ## user  system elapsed 
   ## 8.16    0.02    8.26 

b1
##        original     bias    std. error
## t1* 410.8155650  9.2896499 198.6877889
## t2*   5.7598070  0.5748503   2.5725441
## t3*  -0.6152727 -0.1200954   0.7829191

b2
##        original     bias    std. error
## t1* 410.8155650  9.2896499 198.6877889
## t2*   5.7598070  0.5748503   2.5725441
## t3*  -0.6152727 -0.1200954   0.7829191
```