# Block bootstrap from subject list, extract coefficients in PROC MIXED

Tags: sas, regression, statistics-bootstrap

I'm trying to efficiently implement a block bootstrap technique to get the distribution of regression coefficients from `PROC MIXED`. The main outline is as follows:

I have a panel data set, say `firm` and `year` are the indices. For each iteration of the bootstrap, I wish to sample with replacement n subjects. From this sample, I need to construct a new data set that is a "stack" (concatenated row on top of row) of all the observations for each sampled subject. With this new data set, I can run the regression and pull out the coefficients of interest. Repeat for a bunch of iterations, say 2000.

Each firm can potentially be selected multiple times, so I need to include its data multiple times in each iteration's data set.
Using a loop and subset approach, seems computationally burdensome.
My real data set quite large (a 2Gb .sas7bdat file).

Example pseudo/explanatory code (please pardon all noob errors!):

```
DATA subjectlist;
  SET mydata;
  BY firm;
  IF first.firm;
RUN;

%macro blockboot(input=, subjects=, iterations=);

%let numberfirms = LENGTH(&subjects);

  %do i = 1 %to &iterations ;
    DATA mytempdat;
      DO i=1 TO &numberfirms;
        rec = ceil(&numberfirms * ranuni(0));

        *** This is where I want to include all observations for the randomly selected subjects;
        *** However, this code doesn't include the same subject multiple times, which...;
        *** ...is what I want;
        SET &INPUT subjects IN &subjects;

      OUTPUT;
      END;
     STOP;

  PROC MIXED DATA=mytempdat; 
    CLASS firm year; 
    MODEL yval= cov1 cov2; 
    RANDOM intercept /sub=subject type=un; 
    OUTPUT out=outx cov1=cov1 ***want to output the coefficient estimate on cov1 here;
  RUN; 

    %IF &i = 1 %THEN %DO;
      DATA outall;
        SET outx;
      %END;
    %ELSE %DO;
      PROC APPEND base=outall data=outx;
      %END;
    %END;  /* i=1 to &REPS loop */

  PROC UNIVARIATE data=outall;
    VAR cov1;
    OUTPUT out=final pctlpts=2.5, 97.5 pctlpre=ci;

%mend;

%blockboot(input=mydata,subjects=subjectlist, reps=2000)
```

This question is identical to a question I asked previously, found here:

[block bootstrap from subject list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919808/block-bootstrap-from-subject-list)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

See the following paper for details on the best way to do this in SAS:

http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2007/183-2007.pdf

The general summary is to use PROC SURVEYSELECT with a method that allows sampling with replacement to create your bootstrap sample, then use BY processing with PROC MIXED to run the PROC only once rather than running it 2000 times.